# Vectorize numpy array for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to figure out how to vectorize the following loop:

```
for i in range(1,size):
    if a[i] < a[i-1]:
        b[i] = a[i]
    else: b[i] = b[i-1]
```

b is a (large) array of the same size as a.
I could use

```
numpy.where(a[1:]<a[:-1])
```

to replace the if statement but how do you simultaneously replace the else statement?

Comment: I don't think this can be vectorized, since each element depends on the previous one.

Comment: This is a guess, but the `vectorize` docs say it the vectorizing function accepts a *sequence*. Could you rewrite your loop as a generator instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(a, b):
    # cond is a boolean array marking where the condition is met
    cond = a[1:] < a[:-1]
    cond = np.insert(cond, 0, False)
    # values is an array of the items in from a that will be used to fill b
    values = a[cond]
    values = np.insert(values, 0, b[0])
    # labels is an array of increasing indices into values
    label = cond.cumsum()
    b[:] = values[label]
```

Comment: This did it thanks. Now to make sure I understand it and then test it for speed.

Comment: I hope this gives you some speedup. If you have more information about b, you might be able to get even more of a speedup. For example if you know ahead of time that b should be monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> `numpy.where(condition[, x, y])`
>
> > Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.

So you can simplify a loop containing:

```
if cond:
    a[i] = b[i]
else:
    a[i] = c[i]
```

to

```
a = numpy.where(cond, a, b)
```

However, I don't think your example can be vectorized, since each element depends on the previous one.

Comment: I think you're right. So what options are there to speed up an operation such as this if vectorizing is not possible?